# What is Context Means in extended button class? What is default of a Context?

Tags: java, android, class, android-context, extended-events

This is my extended button class`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Hotel extends Button{
    String  id;
    String name;
    String company_id;

    public Hotel(Context context, String id, String name, String company_id) {
        super(context);
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.company_id = company_id;
    }
}
```

What is Context in an extended button class constructure parameter?

I want to use this class as an array in an other class but i am not sure what sould i write in Context place? İam tring to get hotel buttons from soap service and using this codes below. This GetHotels method is in an other class. I am just confused about that Context thing. Help me please.

```
 import android.content.Context;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

/**
 * Created by arzucaki on 09/05/2017.
 */

public class ServiceManager {
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetHotels";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetHotels";
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.170/HotelApps_WebServices.asmx";
    public static Context mContext;
    SoapObject soapObject;
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapSerializationEnvelope;
    HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE;

    public Hotel[] GetHotels(int Company_id) {

        soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        soapObject.addProperty("Company_id", Company_id);

        soapSerializationEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapSerializationEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapSerializationEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);

        httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        httpTransportSE.debug = true;

        Hotel hotels[]=new Hotel[6];
        try {
            httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapSerializationEnvelope);
            SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive=(SoapPrimitive)soapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse();
            JSONArray jsonHotels = new JSONArray(soapPrimitive.toString());

            for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
                hotels[i]=new Hotel( mContext, jsonHotels.getJSONObject(i).getString("Hotel_id"),jsonHotels.getJSONObject(i).getString("Hotel_Name"), jsonHotels.getJSONObject(i).getString("Company_id"));

            }
            return hotels;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return hotels;
        }
    }

}
```

I am calling the method right here

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridLayout;

public class Hotels extends AppCompatActivity {
    ServiceManager service=new ServiceManager();;
    Hotel hotels[];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotels);
        GridLayout glHotels=(GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.glHotels);

        Thread getHotels=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                hotels=service.GetHotels(1);
            }
        });
        getHotels.start();
        for (int i=0; i<hotels.length; i++) {
            glHotels.addView(hotels[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: pass getApplicationContext() as an argument in context

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean this: Hotel hotel = new Hotel(getApplicationContext(),......)

Comment: Ok i did but this class has no activity i am using this class only for service management. Thats why it doesnt work.

Comment: getApplicationContext() does not need an activity works well from a plain class

Comment: So what should i import cuz it couldnt define getApplicationContext()

Comment: What is Your requirement??

Comment: Tell me Your requirement clearly

Comment: İ need to get hotel attributes as a hotel array from soap web service(it returns values as json string)but hotel array has to be a button.

Comment: the method getHotels() can u post the entire class?

Comment: from where did u start this service class?? which activity? i need to see the constructor of this service class

Comment: i updated the question. put the whole class

Comment: How are u starting this service class??

Comment: I can see a context variable public static Context mContext; in the global where are u instantiating it??

Comment: First tell me how are u accessing the method getHotels()  ??

Comment: i just tried it it doesnt work. i didnt instantate it.

Comment: how are u accessing the method getHotels() ?? I think this service will not work.did u check response??

Comment: i am accesing gethotels only from the codes you see in the service class nothing else using ksoap2-android-asembly-2.4

Comment: i checked response it works fine actually if i dont extend to button my hotel class everything is ok.

Comment: Where are u calling the method getHotels ??show me that specific line where ur calling this method

Comment: if u show me where this method gets called,i can solve this issue for u

Comment: ok adding to the question wait.

Comment: i addded to the question

Comment: I am adding the answer check it out

Comment: ok thanks a lot i am holding on.

Comment: plz upvote it,if it helped u.Thank u

Comment: did it work?? @arzucaki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method signature of ur ServiceManager Class like this:

```
public class ServiceManager {
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetHotels";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetHotels";
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.170/HotelApps_WebServices.asmx";
    public static Context mContext;
    SoapObject soapObject;
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapSerializationEnvelope;
    HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE;
public ServiceManager(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;//now u can pass mContext to Hotel Constructor
}
    public Hotel[] GetHotels(int Company_id) {

        soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        soapObject.addProperty("Company_id", Company_id);

        soapSerializationEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapSerializationEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapSerializationEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);

        httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        httpTransportSE.debug = true;

        Hotel hotels[]=new Hotel[6];
        try {
            httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapSerializationEnvelope);
            SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive=(SoapPrimitive)soapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse();
            JSONArray jsonHotels = new JSONArray(soapPrimitive.toString());

            for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
                hotels[i]=new Hotel( mContext, jsonHotels.getJSONObject(i).getString("Hotel_id"),jsonHotels.getJSONObject(i).getString("Hotel_Name"), jsonHotels.getJSONObject(i).getString("Company_id"));

            }
            return hotels;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return hotels;
        }
    }

}
```

In the Activity Class initialize service manager like this:

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridLayout;

public class Hotels extends AppCompatActivity {
    ServiceManager service=new ServiceManager(getApplicationContext());
    Hotel hotels[];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotels);
        GridLayout glHotels=(GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.glHotels);

        Thread getHotels=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                hotels=service.GetHotels(1);
            }
        });
        getHotels.start();
        for (int i=0; i<hotels.length; i++) {
            glHotels.addView(hotels[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error:(8, 28) error: constructor ServiceManager in class ServiceManager cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Check the Updated Activty Class and make changes accordingly

Comment: it gives an run time error "application has stoped" but i control array in debug mode it was ok. Application stops but it returns the hotels as an array.

Comment: upvote it if u found it was helpful,u need to solve other errors on ur own

Comment: Ty ;) happy coding